# Visualising crossed random effect for lme

Tags: r, plot, lme4

I am new to mixed models and have some problems. I've got a model:

`lmer(F2 ~ (phoneme|individual) + (1|word) + age + frequency + (1|zduration), data = nurse_female)`

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: 
F2 ~ (phoneme | individual) + (1 | word) + age + frequency +  
    (1 | zduration)
   Data: nurse_female

REML criterion at convergence: 654.4

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.09203 -0.20332  0.03263  0.25273  1.37056 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
 zduration  (Intercept) 0.27779  0.5271              
 word       (Intercept) 0.04488  0.2118              
 individual (Intercept) 0.34181  0.5846              
            phonemeIr   0.54227  0.7364   -0.82      
            phonemeVr   1.52090  1.2332   -0.93  0.91
 Residual               0.06326  0.2515              
Number of obs: 334, groups:  
zduration, 280; word, 116; individual, 23

Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)         1.79167    0.32138   5.575
age                -0.01596    0.00508  -3.142
frequencylow       -0.37587    0.18560  -2.025
frequencymid       -1.18901    0.27738  -4.286
frequencyvery high -0.68365    0.26564  -2.574

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) age    frqncyl frqncym
age         -0.811                       
frequencylw -0.531 -0.013                
frequencymd -0.333 -0.006  0.589         
frqncyvryhg -0.356  0.000  0.627   0.389
```

The model predicts the normalised formant values of vowels such in NURSE for female speakers. Without getting too much into it, there are roughly 3 variants possible that I coded under phoneme as <Er, Ir, Vr>. Individual describes the speaker. I managed to plot the F2 variance of each speaker using random effects.

But how do I plot the model predictions for the F2 values for each speaker with phoneme on the x-axis (i.e. 3 marks for <Er, Ir, Vr>) and F2 on the y-axis?

I tried a few ways but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance. If you need further information/data just say so